# How to become a Fiware community team member?

Tags: fiware-orion

FIWARE is an open cloud-based infrastructure for creation and delivery of Internet applications and services. I would like to join Fiware community team.

What are the steps to join FIWARE Community team?

Comment: This question probably should be posted at https://ask.fiware.org/questions. Note that StackOverflow is for technical questions and this one is not of technical nature...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or related to programming.

Comment: Here you have a tutorial about upgrading to community account: https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE_Lab:_Upgrade_to_Community_Account

Answer (score 0):

the best way to contribute is to contribute with documentation, tutorials, code for the main projects of the Fiware Community:

- Orion
- IoT Agents
- Cygnus
- Wirecloud
- Knowage

...